# Importing modules from parent folder does not work when running flask app

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to import module from file in my parent directory but is not working

Here is how my directory looks like :

[image]

Here is how my main.py file looks like :

```
import sys
path_modules="./Utils"
sys.path.append(path_modules)
from functools import lru_cache

from flask import Flask, render_template, request



import Utils.HardSoftClassifier as cl
import Utils.prediction_utils as ut
import Utils.DataPrepper_reg as prep

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/viz')
def viz():
    return render_template('viz.html')
    


if __name__=="__main__":
#    import os
#    os.system("start microsoft-edge:http:\\localhost:5000/")
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my flaks output :

[image]

Comment: What's the structure of the `Utils` directory?

Comment: Utlils is a folder as you can see on the picture

Comment: I was asking for its structure not its type. Especially does it have an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: Furthermore, could you also share how do you start the app? From which directory and the actual command.

Comment: @Dauros the Directory Clean_code as you can see in the picture and I run the command "Flask run"

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file inside the `Utils` directory?

Comment: No I do not have

Comment: What do I need to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order [to make a package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) importable, it must have an (optionally empty) `__init__.py` file in its root. So first create an empty `__init__.py` file in the `Utils` directory.

Furthermore, you don't have to alter the import path, since you start the Flask app from the `Clean_code`, the simple relative importing will work. So the first three line can be removed from `main.py`.